# creating .mid file: writing a '\n' causes '\r\n' in Windows

Tags: c, windows, ascii, midi

I have created a `.mid` file by writing bytes to a file and save it as `.midi`. I can run it and it works, but there are some special cases where it does not.

If I write a byte containing `\n` (ASCII `10`) then it will instead write 2 bytes `\r\n`, which makes the `.mid` not runnable. (This is normal for Windows machine to do, but not desirable in my case.) An example of writing `\n` could be when picking the key which is being represented by `\n`.

Is there a workaround to write `\n` and not `\r\n` or another way to make sure that byte written is ASCII `10` on a Windows machine?

Thanks!

Comment: What code are you using to write the bytes?

Comment: just open your file in binary mode `fopen("file.out","wb")` to avoid linefeed conversion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On linux/unix, it doesn't matter whether you specify `"wb"` or `"w"` to create a file.

But creating a text file using `fopen` in windows means that all `\n` are converted to `\r\n`, so if you're using this to create binary files, the binary files will be "corrupt" if there are some bytes with value "10" (linefeed)

Simple solution: always use `fopen("file.bin","wb")` when creating a binary file, on all platforms so your code is portable.